# What is the efficiency of the machine (probability theory)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A machine is made of 5 parts. Its efficiency deppends on the efficiency of each of the 5 parts. What is the efficiency of the machine, if the probabiliy that each of the parts is broken equals $P=10\%$?

The machine is represented like this:

$$-T1-T2-T3-T4-T5-$$

Comment: How do we model the efficiency of the whole system? Is it completely down if at least one parts is broken? Or is it only 80 percent efficient if one is broken?

Comment: The parts are connected in series, so the machine to run has to have all five parts in good conditions. P(broken part i)=1-P(not broken part i).